# angular-google-maps: could not find a valid center property?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get angular-google-maps to work. I've got everything setup per the instructions, but I can't seem to get around this error:

angular-google-maps: could not find a valid center property

I've got this in my page controller:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
   center: {
    latitude: 0, // initial map center latitude
    longitude: 0, // initial map center longitude
   },
   markers: [], // an array of markers,
   zoom: 8, // the zoom level
});
```

And this in my html

```
<google-map center="center" zoom="zoom" markers="markers" refresh="!isMapElementHidden" style="height: 400px"></google-map>
```

Few points:
 - It seems that the angular-google-maps directive code is being called before my controller code, so the $scope.center variable is not created yet

- When I hardcode a center in it works
- I try this, but without any luck as the map never updates to the new cope values set in the controller:

  center="center ? center : {latitude: 36.990282103105066, longitude: -122.06149578094482}"
- I've also tried to implement Angular Leaflet maps and get the exact same problem

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide a plunkr a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: the longitude should not have a ',' after it, neither should zoom, as its not valid json. although this may be ignored

Answer (score 5):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/g2mYM/4/)

you are not passing the center property moreover i recommend you to use the [r1-dev](https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/tree/r1-dev) branch directive rather than [master](https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/tree/master) branch directive of angular-google-maps, pass the parameters like this

```
 angular.extend($scope, {
        centerProperty: {
            lat: 45,
            lng: -73
        },
        zoomProperty: 8,
        markersProperty: [ {
                latitude: 45,
                longitude: -74
            }],
        clickedLatitudeProperty: null,  
        clickedLongitudeProperty: null,
    });
```

or you can also use

```
position: {
  coords: {
    latitude: 36.990282103105066,
    longitude: -122.06149578094482
  }
},
```

Comment: r1-dev branch is broken. This project must be moving fast. I've been trying to integrate with it all day.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was using an older version of angular-google-maps that expected center to have lat and lng properties rather than latitude longitude.

Also worth noting: as of 2.0.7 the module is defined as uiGmapgoogle-maps and the map directive is ui-gmap-google-map